# array in array to array in numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, sympy

Dear friends in stack overflow,
I have trouble calculation with Numpy and Sympy. A is defined by

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

sym.var('x y')
f = sym.Matrix([0,x,y])
func = sym.lambdify( (x,y), f, "numpy")

X=np.array([1,2,3])
Y=np.array((1,2,3])

A = func(X,Y).
```

Here, X and Y are just examples. In general, X and Y are one dimensional array in numpy, and they have the same length. Then, A’s output is

```
array([[0],
       [array([1, 2, 3])],
       [array([1, 2, 3])]], dtype=object).
```

But, I'd like to get this as

```
np.array([[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]).
```

If we call this B, How do you convert A to B automatically. B’s first column is filled by 0, and it has the same length with X and Y.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by you want to set `$B_{0i}$ as 0`? This comes off to me as wanting to set the first element in each array within the array to 0. It would be [0,0,0] [0,2,3] and [0,2,3] using this logic. Correct me if I you meant something else..

Comment: Thank for very much for your question. I corrected some typos and expressions. I’d like to get B which satisfies the above condition...

Comment: So in padding the zero's, is it safe to assume all the arrays in `A` except for the first one will be of the same `length` (3 in this case for example)?

Comment: Also, I'm getting some `module 'object' not callable` error. Can you specify your `import` statement(s) please?

Comment: I updated my question. The derivation of A was modified, and the additional comment about B’s padding was added.

Comment: I can't get it to run without the errors :( My environment isn't picking up the numpy or sympy modules.

Comment: `x` and  `y` in the numpy function are variables but `0` is not  `numpy` can't expand that to match `x` in shape.

Answer (score 0):

First let's make sure we understand what is happening:

```
In [52]: x, y = symbols('x y')
In [54]: f = Matrix([0,x,y])
    ...: func = lambdify( (x,y), f, "numpy")
In [55]: f
Out[55]: 
⎡0⎤
⎢ ⎥
⎢x⎥
⎢ ⎥
⎣y⎦

In [56]: print(func.__doc__)
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(x, y)

Expression:

Matrix([[0], [x], [y]])

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(x, y):
    return (array([[0], [x], [y]]))
```

See how the `numpy` function looks just like the `sympy`, replacing `sym.Matrix` with `np.array`.  `lambdify` just does a lexographic translation; it does not have a deep knowledge of the differences between the languages.

With scalars the `func` runs as expected:

```
In [57]: func(1,2)
Out[57]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

With arrays the results is this ragged array (new enough numpy adds this warning:

```
In [59]: func(np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([1,2,3]))
<lambdifygenerated-2>:2: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  return (array([[0], [x], [y]]))
Out[59]: 
array([[0],
       [array([1, 2, 3])],
       [array([1, 2, 3])]], dtype=object)
```

If you don't know `numpy`, `sympy` is not a short cut to filling in your knowledge gaps.

The simplest fix is to replace original `0` with another symbol.

Even in `sympy`, the 0 is not expanded:

```
In [65]: f.subs({x:Matrix([[1,2,3]]), y:Matrix([[4,5,6]])})
Out[65]: 
⎡    0    ⎤
⎢         ⎥
⎢[1  2  3]⎥
⎢         ⎥
⎣[4  5  6]⎦

In [74]: Matrix([[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
Out[74]: 
⎡0  0  0⎤
⎢       ⎥
⎢1  2  3⎥
⎢       ⎥
⎣4  5  6⎦

In [75]: Matrix([[0],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
...
ValueError: mismatched dimensions
```

To make the desired array in `numpy` we have to do something like:

```
In [71]: arr = np.zeros((3,3), int)
In [72]: arr[1:,:] = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
In [73]: arr
Out[73]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

That is, initial the array and fill selected rows.  There isn't simple expression that will do the desired 'automaticlly fill the first row with 0', much less something that can be naively translated from `sympy`.